# How to make negative rules in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, http, apache-virtualhost

I have a virtualhost which I configured to redirect any hit to a different site, so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect 301 / http://other.site/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I would like to re-configure it on a way, that it should redirect *any hit, except to a specific virtual directory*. Intuitively, I would think some similar:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location ! "/subdir">
    Redirect 301 / http://other.site/
  </Location>
  ...configuration for /subdir...
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it in Apache possible? As I understood its config, it is not very strong in any negative rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You can use *RedirectMatch* with the [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) Apache module, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!subdir...)(.*) http://other.site/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or you can use Apache's [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module and do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir...
    RewriteRule (.*) http://other.site/ [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```